# How to rotate an SKSpriteNode by 360° before go to angle

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I was faced with a problem today when I wanted to make a 360° rotation of a spritenode before go to a specified angle, I found a way but I don't know if this is the best.

I tried many ways and **this code doesn't work** as expected:

```
let angle = CGFloat(self.angle * number) // angle in degrees
let flip  = CGFloat(360+angle).degreesToRadians // 360°+angle in radians
SKAction.rotateToAngle(-flip, duration: 0.4, shortestUnitArc:false)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying differents methods this code works as expected, it makes a complete loop before rotate to the angle. Is this the best way?

```
let angle = CGFloat(self.angle * number)
let flip  = CGFloat(360+angle).degreesToRadians
let needleTurn = SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.rotateToAngle(-flip/2, duration: 0.2, shortestUnitArc:true),
    SKAction.rotateToAngle(-flip, duration: 0.2, shortestUnitArc:false)
])
```